# Calling $.ajax inside form validator

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-validate

How can I write a `$.ajax()` call within jQuery validate's `submitHandler()`? Below is my code. I have only one text that is `Empname`.

```js
$('#FormSubmit').validate({
  rules: {
    EmpName: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 10
    },
    meassages: {
      EmpName: {
        required: function() {
          return $('#lblName').text('Name Req min2 max15');
        }
        submitHandler: function(FormSubmit) {
          $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/PostData",
            method: "POST",
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            success: function() {

            }
          })
        },
```

```html
<form id="FormSubmit" method="post">
  <div class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <b>EmpName</b><input type="text" name="EmpName" required />
      <span id="lblName"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

It's not handling my `url` and also its giving me an error:

> HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Comment: where is  the ajax $ call?

Comment: Put it in the `submitHandler` callback

Comment: @Alvaro i just updated my code plz review

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly note that you have several syntax issues, such as not closing objects correctly, `messages` is incorrectly typed and the `required` message needs to return a string value.

Secondly, the `submitHandler` is just a function that gets executed when the form is valid. You need to put your actual `$.ajax` logic inside it, not just the request parameters:

```js
$('#FormSubmit').validate({
  rules: {
    EmpName: {
      required: true,
      minlength: 5,
      maxlength: 10
    }
  },
  messages: {
    EmpName: {
      required: 'Name Req min2 max15'
    }
  },
  submitHandler: function(form) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:10948/Api/Home/PostData",
      method: "POST",
      data: $(form).serialize(),
      success: function(response) {
        console.log('it worked!');
        console.log(response);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: ... that's what this code is doing. If it's not working, check the console for errors

Comment: Getting error as HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed

Comment: In which case you sure the API supports POST requests to that endpoint? Try GET instead. In either case that's a separate problem as the request is clearly being made. I'd suggest you start a new question about it, making sure you include your API code too.

Comment: I decorated its [HttpPost]

Comment: Are you using jQuery v1.9 or newer? `method` was only added as a property from then. Try `type: 'POST'`

Comment: @Roy Thank u sooo much for urs valuable time